# How do i change the icon of my new Android app in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I made an app using Android Studio. I created the signed apk and copied that to my phone. Installed the apk in my phone, but now the icon of this app is the default Android icon. How can i change this and make a new one. And how do i change the name of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For setting app icon goto **AndroidManifest.xml** under `<application` tag there will an attribute `android:icon` where you can set your desired icon.For example: `android:icon="@drawable/sample_image"`
where **sample_image** is name of the image to be set which is placed under **/res/drawable/** folder.

For setting app name goto **strings.xml** and look for:

`<string name="app_name">` and change the value of that string as desired.